# dhtmlxgantt get a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toLowerCase') when i toggle fullscreen

Tags: reactjs, dhtmlx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zHt0.png)

When I enter or exit gantt fullscreen by calling the ganttRef.expand()/ganttRef.collapse() method, I got this error.
Can someone tell me roughly what went wrong, or how to fix it

The program didn't crash, but I expect no errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPsLU.png)

Is it listening to errors caused by gantt reconfiguring the layout in fullscreen mode

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce the issue with the simple configuration (without custom layout configuration):
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/jxobzydw

And the issue is not reproduced with the custom layout configuration:
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/jwwjqbuc

https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/c7ifv2ig

It is hard to suggest what might be wrong as I don't see your code.
Please add your configuration to the following snippet and make sure that the issue is reproduced there:
https://snippet.dhtmlx.com/40tsh9uz

Then, click on the `Save` button and send me the link.
Or send me a ready demo with all the necessary JavaScript and CSS files so that I can reproduce the issue locally.